# How to map fields by stream api

Tags: java, stream

I have a simple class:

```
class Note {
    public int id;
    public String status;
    // some other fields....
}
```

and I'm want to map fields of this class by the stream api. I have a simple implementation of method, that do what I'm want:

```
public function(int externalId) {
    Set<Note> notes = getFromRepository(); // simple method for getting all Note from repository
    for (Note note : notes){
        note.setId(externalId);
        note.setStatus("Open");
    }
}
```

How I can do it with Stream api?

Answer (score 2):

Map is not really appropriate here because

1. setters don't typically return a value (although you can fudge it), and
2. map is not a terminal operation so you would need some unnecessary terminal operation to trigger the stream.

But there is nothing gained by using a stream here.  And since `getFromRespository` returns a set you can use the Set interface's `forEach` method directly.

```
public void function(int externalId) {
     getFromRespository().forEach(note->{
                     note.setID(externalId);
                     note.setStatus("Open");
    });
}
```

BTW, there is nothing wrong with your existing implementation.  As you said, it is "simple", and therefore is easy to understand.